# How Can I Remove These Unwanted Lines in my Blender Render?

Tags: rendering, bevel

For some reason, these unwanted lines keep appearing in my render output. They appear near beveled edges. I can't find a way to get rid of them. I'm using shade smooth and auto smooth. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of your topology. You have a big ngon face on top and bottom.

One way (the brute force method) to solve this is you could add a remesh modifier, set to sharp, octree depth something bigger than 6 (maybe 8) and then render again.

Comment: perfect. Thanks.

Comment: you are welcome